# How can I store the value a user enters in a variable?

Tags: application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

How can I store the value a user enters in a variable?

For example I have this code:

```
TextField {width: 37; height: 19
                       var 
                       id: q1
                       x: 91
                       y: 29
                       anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                anchors.centerIn: parent
                       placeholderText: "0"
                       font.pixelSize: 12
                       text: ""
                       anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 26
                       anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -115
                       validator: IntValidator{}
                       horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
                       style: TextFieldStyle {
                           textColor: "black"
                           background: Rectangle { width: 45; height: 25; radius: 20.0

                               color: "#F0EBEB"
                               implicitWidth: 40
                               implicitHeight: 24
                               border.color: "#000000"
                               border.width: 1
                           }
                       }
                       onTextChanged: {console.log(parseInt(text,10) + 1000)}
                   }
```

Can I use the id to later use and make the sum or the multiplication? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse the text property outside the TextField component.

Look at the following example where a Text element shows the result of the Input text + 5:

[image]

The corresponding code:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

MainView {
    id: main
    width: 300
    height: 150

    Row {
        width: 37;
        height: 19
        spacing: units.gu(3)

        TextField {
            id: q1
            placeholderText: "0"
            font.pixelSize: 12
            text: "0"
            validator: IntValidator{}
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter

            style: TextFieldStyle {
                textColor: "black"
                background: Rectangle {
                    width: 45;
                    height: 25;
                    radius: 20.0
                    color: "#F0EBEB"
                    implicitWidth: 40
                    implicitHeight: 24
                    border.color: "#000000"
                    border.width: 1
                }
            }
        }

        Text {
            height: 25;
            text: "TextField + 5 = "+(parseInt(q1.text, 10) + 5)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**:

To store the sum of two text input globally you could define a property in the parent element, look at the following code:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

MainView {
    id: main
    width: 300
    height: 300
    property var sum_q1_q2: parseInt(q1.text, 10) + parseInt(q2.text, 10)

    Column {
        width: 37;
        height: 19
        spacing: units.gu(3)

        TextField {
            id: q1
            placeholderText: "0"
            font.pixelSize: 12
            text: "0"
            validator: IntValidator{}
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter

            style: TextFieldStyle {
                textColor: "black"
                background: Rectangle {
                    width: 45;
                    height: 25;
                    radius: 20.0
                    color: "#F0EBEB"
                    implicitWidth: 40
                    implicitHeight: 24
                    border.color: "#000000"
                    border.width: 1
                }
            }
        }

        TextField {
            id: q2
            placeholderText: "0"
            font.pixelSize: 12
            text: "0"
            validator: IntValidator{}
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter

            style: TextFieldStyle {
                textColor: "black"
                background: Rectangle {
                    width: 45;
                    height: 25;
                    radius: 20.0
                    color: "#F0EBEB"
                    implicitWidth: 40
                    implicitHeight: 24
                    border.color: "#000000"
                    border.width: 1
                }
            }
        }

        Text {
            height: 25;
            text: "Q1 + Q2 = "+main.sum_q1_q2
        }
    }
}
```

The new Text element now use the property of the "main" component:

[image]

Comment: Sylvain how can i do an internal sum like q1.text plus q2.text and store that in variable that i'll call later on??

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example where q1.text + q2.text is stored in a component property.

Comment: and how can i make this: create a new variable by doing for exemple t = q1.text + (q2.text/60) and then store that value and use later on to do for example i have another var like t and i want to multiplie x with t that create var Y divided by 1000 that create var k and to finish off k x 0.101 . is this possible??

Comment: Diogo, create a new question to cover this please. But a quick answer would be to dedicate the computation work to a js function.

Comment: Sylvain ty for your help i'll see how to create the js function